# CSS: can I scale an image including its container?

Tags: css, css-paged-media

I've got a section of text, with an image in between paragraphs.

```
<p class="bodytext">aslkjfsdlkfj f ldflskl</p>
<p class="image"><img src=1.png/></p>
<p class="bodytext">aslkjfsdlkfj f ldflskl</p>
```

The image dimensions are not specified in the HTML, they're read from the image.
I want to use CSS to scale the image:

```
img {
    transform: scale(0.7);
}
```

However, this only scales the image and not the box that contains it, so I get a huge gap between the text and image. I want to get rid of this gap.

- Setting top/bottom margins does not work
- there's the 'transform-box:' property that sounds like it should do what I need, but none of the settings make any difference.

Application: CSS Paged Media in Antennahouse Formatter.

Comment: An image can only take it's actual width or a designated size. if you use % size it will be a % of the parent container. Seems to me you want to just use smaller images.

Comment: You could select the paragraph that has the image IF `:has` was supported in any browser.

Comment: I don't need :has, I've got a unique paragraph style for the para that contains the image. I tried applying the scaling to p.image, but that doesn't get rid of the gap.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using smaller images: I want to be able to use the same image in A4 and A5 publications: the A4 uses the image at its original size, in A5 the same image should be scaled to 70%.

Comment: As I said, you can only change the size of the image in the paragraph by setting it to a specific size (in the unit of your choice) or a % size of the paragraph itself.. Maybe a media query but there I leave my area of expertise

Comment: @K J it looks like you're using max-width to scale the image depending on the viewport size. That can be done on `<img>` tags as well, no need to change to `<picture>`. Unfortunately max-sidth is not enough, the customer specifically wants to scale the images to 70% of their original size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Antennahouse Formatter-specific instruction will scale an image including its container:

```
img {
-ah-content-width: 70%;
}
```

You can also use -ah-content-height, scaling is proportional by default.

This was designed to match behavior in [XSLFO](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xsl11-20061205/#content-width): it will scale the image to n% of the image's intrinsic size.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution #1 using *zoom*

**There is a non-standard `zoom` CSS property which gives you precisely what you need.** `Zoom` will always scale the whole element, not only its inner contents, and works for any kind of HTML elements: block, inline, replaced elements (images) or text.

```
img {
  zoom: 75%;
}
```

Although [the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) says that *"transform: scale() should be used instead"*, it also explains that these two properties works differently, as *"unlike CSS Transforms, zoom affects the layout size of the element"* – which is exactly what you need in your case.

The browser support for `zoom` is very good. CanIUse [states 94.5% support](https://caniuse.com/css-zoom). Note, however, that `zoom` is really a non-standard property – don't use it on your production sites, although *in fact*, it is supported by every major browser *except* Firefox. At the same time, in your setup, where all you need is to print HTML materials (let's say to PDF) by yourself, this should be ideal.

See working JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/FurloSK/8bhzkrw2/

### EDIT (see comment from OP below)

#### Solution #2 using *transform: scale()* with fixed-size container

Well, there *is* a way to force the image element to scale and also scale its container, but there are two catches:

1. First, it is abusing several CSS properties, and since you are not using a common browser like Chrome, but a specific software (Antennahouse Formatter), I have doubts whether this will actually work for you.
2. Secondly, you will have to manually specify the container size (which kind of defeats the purpose of determining it automatically). Still, I am writing this down here for reference's sake, as it is actually something I am using on a [site of my own](https://ja2.furlo.sk/) (a reference page for a computer game) and **it is a proper solution to a question "how to scale an image including its container?"** – although not practical for your specific case.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="fixedContainer">
  <img class="smallScale" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"/>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.fixedContainer {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80px; /* 100px * scale(0.75) = 75px */
  height: 80px; /* 100px * scale(0.75) = 75px */
}
.fixedContainer .smallScale {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Again, see working JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/FurloSK/8bhzkrw2/

#### Solution #3 Using *width* property with auto-fit-sized container

This last solution *should* work for you. Its simple and no ugly hacks are used: you just scale down an image with CSS `width` using [percentage value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#values) and set the `width` of the outer container to match its elements with `fit-content`. Container will get its size from original image size, therefore giving its nested image element a reference value of what "100%" means, and image can then be scaled  by percentage value.

*Note that without the `fit-content` part, div would have no size of its own, and image's percentage width would refer to the whole page – or nearest ancestor with defined width.*

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="fitContainer">
  <img class="smallWidth" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.fitContainer {
  width: fit-content;
}
.fitContainer .smallWidth {
  width: 75%;
}
```

Finally, see working JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/FurloSK/8bhzkrw2/

Comment: unfortunately the Zoom function doesn't seem to be supported in Antennahouse Formatter.

Comment: @Hobbes see my edited answer ;-)

Comment: width: fit-content is not supported in Antennahouse Formatter. Upvoted for creative effort though.